# Поменять OnclickListener кнопке в Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Ребят помогите.Мне нужно,чтобы моя кнопка по нажатию меняла своего `OnclickListener`.

Android studio не может найти `oncl2`. Как можно его объявить или как-то по другому заставить кнопку менять по нажатию свой `OnclickListener`?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Сделайте `final OnClickListener oncl1,oncl2` переменными класса.

После `public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity{`

Поставьте `final OnClickListener oncl1,oncl2;`

а в процедуре объявления уберите,оставьте просто

```
oncl1 = new View.OnClickListener() {....};
oncl2 = new View.OnClickListener() {....};
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное !!!Вы очень помогли))